# Как правильно подключить вёрстку к шаблону Spring Initializr - Spring Boot Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, war

Наваял свой первый html на несколько страниц, но застопорился с подключением стилей и скриптов в Thymeleaf.
Структура дефолтного проекта в IDEA 2017.2 Ultimate.[image: Структура дефолтного проекта в IDEA]

index.html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link th:href="@{/css/mdb.min.css}" href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
<link th:href="@{/css/custom.css}" href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<----->

<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/popper.min.js}" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/popper.min.js}" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/mdb.min.js}" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/tota11y.min.js}" src="js/tota11y.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/popper.js}" src="js/popper.js"></script>
<script>
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

в /static/ должны лежать стили, скрипты и т.д. , а
в /templates/ свои странички

Comment: Спасибо. да уже давно решил и забыл)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное index.html переложить в папку templates.
А здесь:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Эта часть:

```
th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}
```

По идее равнозначна:

```
src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
```

Потому, должно хватить:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}"></script>
```